# C# ASP.NET - Not able to hide image in updateprogress after response redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, updateprogress

I have one Ajax UpdateProgress for only one UpdatePanels in the page.

The updatepanel has a gridview with a download button.

Once user clicks on the button, the 'wait' Image shows up, but keeps showing even after the download is complete.

How should I hide it, once the download is done.

My code below but not working, because the image is showing even after the download is complete.

**.cs**

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton ImageButton1 = (ImageButton)sender;
    sIDint = ImageButton1.CommandArgument.ToString();

    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("ExcelDownloadFlag")
    {
        Value = "Flag",
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
    };
    Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
    Response.Redirect("pdf.aspx?sID=" + sIDint.ToString());

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "HideImage();", true);
    ImageButton imgLike = (ImageButton)FindControl("imgLike");

    if (imgLike != null)
    {
        imgLike.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

**.aspx**

```
function HideImage() {
    $(#imgLike).hide();
}

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Dwn">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server"
            AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div class="modal">
                    <div class="center">
                        <img alt="" src="/Img/ajax-loader.gif" id="imgLike" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ImageButton1" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server"
                    ImageUrl="/img/download.gif"
                    OnClick="ImageButton1_Click"
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Edit**

Solved using

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton ImageButton1 = (ImageButton)sender;
    string sIDint = ImageButton1.CommandArgument.ToString();
 
    Thread.Sleep(3000);
    HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("ExcelDownloadFlag")
    {
        Value = "Flag",
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
    };
    Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "OpenWindow", "window.open('pdf.aspx?sID=" + sIDint + "');", true);
}
```

Comment: You cannot do a Redirect and update the UI at the same time. Also a redirect in an UpdatePanel is not very useful.

Comment: @VDWWD hi thanks for reply. pls see **Edit** on the question.

Comment: Much better, but why the Thread.Sleep(3000);?

Comment: @VDWWD just for a try... was deleted...